# Reorder email accounts in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, email-client

If you have more email accounts in Thunderbird, the accounts are shown in the order of creation.

Now I added a new account and it is shown at the bottom of the list.

How do I change the order of my accounts, so I can set the new account at the top of the list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use add-on [Manually sort folders 1.1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/manually-sort-folders/).

EDIT: Now the link is: [Manually sort folders 2.1.1](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/manually-sort-folders/) (TB ver 68+).

2nd EDIT: Since few last versions of TB, currently 91.5.0, you can order account in Account Settings by dragging the account you wish to move.

Comment: Thanks, you have to restart Thunderbird after sorting again, but that works fine

Comment: @T.Todua: which version of Thunderbird did you test? I'm running version 68.10 and added the add-on via Tools - Add-ons - Search for "sort folders" and installed "Manually sort folders" to Thunderbird. After install I selected Tools - Manually sort folders and followed to UI.

Comment: Thunderbird 78.10.0 (64-bit) definitely use Add-On Manager, via the Tools Menu

Comment: For today the current version is 2.0.6.

Answer (score 24):

To do this without a plugin:

1. Close Thunderbird
2. Backup your profile directory (and most especially `prefs.js`)
3. Using the built-in config editor (or editing `prefs.js` directly), find the `mail.accountmanager.accounts` preference, and change the sequence of the comma-separated account references in it.
4. Find `mail.accountmanager.defaultaccount` and change it, if necessary, to be equal to the account you want to come first.

For example, if the value of `accounts` is `account4,account5,account12`, reflecting a well-worn profile, and you want the third account to be first, change it to `account12,account4,account5`. Then change `defaultaccount` from `account4` to `account12`.

If you aren't sure which account is which, figure out which server configuration is right by looking for `mail.server.serverN.name`, `mail.server.serverN.realhostname`, and/or `mail.server.serverN.userName` (where `N` are different numbers), and then find `mail.account.accountM.server` set to the correct `serverN`.

Inspiration for this answer came from [Thunderbird/Change account order](https://sidvind.com/wiki/Thunderbird/Change_account_order)

Comment: It's the best answer since the add-on mentioned above is not compatible with the last version of Thunderbird. It's also possible to do this via the Configuration editor as described there: https://www.ghacks.net/2015/06/16/how-to-sort-accounts-in-the-email-client-thunderbird-manually/

Comment: This seems to not work anymore. Nothing happens when you edit this setting.

Comment: Can confirm this works with TB 68. @phil294, make sure you're doing the mapping between server and account numbers, and using account numbers for the mail.accountmanager.accounts pref.

Comment: @phil294 : you need to do it while Thunderbird is not running. Otherwise, it will overwrite your changes to prefs.js when exiting.

Answer (score 7):

Since Thunderbird 91, there is an even [simpler way](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/new-thunderbird-91#w_take-control-of-your-email-experience-your-accounts-your-order) without addons and hacks:

1. Right-click any account and select 'Settings' from context menu
2. Drag&drop accounts in the list to the left
3. Done!

Comment: How exactly this does not work for you? Which step fails and how?

Comment: Right, this seems to be a feature of Thunderbird 91. I have updated the answer.

Comment: It seems to be possible to install directly from https://www.thunderbird.net/ instead of using a slightly outdated Ubuntu package.